# ASP.Net Assembly version hell

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have .net c# project that has several references to external DLLs, some are my own core assemblies, and some are 3rd party (like NewtownSoft.Json for example).  When I compile my core assemblies, the compiled DLLs are moved to a local directory (something up from /debug/bin)  such as /development/common/binaries.  My C# project then references my core assemblies here and the core assembly will be copied to the output directory for the project.

Here is the problem, a previous version of the DLL is reference and copied over, from where I do not know, to the output directory.  Not only this, but the DLL class explorer in the project does not reflect the new assembly either.  I've even tried incremementing the version of the core dll and enforcing a Specific Version on the referenced assembly in the project.

Any ideas?  I've researched the topic here and in Google but really not finding a solution.  If this topic has been covered, please inform.  I am compiling 3.5 .NET.

Comment: Have you tried Clean Solution ?

Comment: Are these 'core assemblies' produced by projects in the same solution?  If not they are no different to external assemblies and will always be copied from where you first referenced them.  If they are in the same solution and were added as references to projects in the solution then something is bugged, I'd recreate the solution.

Comment: the assembly might be copied because one of the referenced assemblies uses this version. Have a look in the project files (in a text editor) which assemblies are referenced and from which path they come from.

Comment: Keith, yes I have tried cleaning the solution many times.
James, my external assemblies are compiled in a separate solution all together.
Slfan, this very might be the issue.  I will check my other assembly references for something that might be referencing an older version of it.

Comment: Do you have any test projects that reference older versions? Those will copy into the output directory last usually. I saw a similar problem a few weeks ago like this. One thing you can do it use a program like AgentRansack to go through the project files looking for references to the bad versions.

Comment: @MikeCheel see previous reply to slfan as I think this might be the issue.

Comment: It could be that for the third party stuff OR or you have missed a reference somewhere in your code. If it is your code, try the agent ransack thing I described to find out which one.

Comment: If you're looking for a single specific file, this tool is the fastest thing on earth and krypton.        http://www.voidtools.com/download.php

Comment: The issue has been resolved.  Indeed there was a DLL referenced in my core assembly that was not up to date in my references.  After I copied this dll along with the core dll to my shared binaries folder the project compiled correctly.  I would be nice if you got a compile error of some sort because obviously .NET decides to throw out your reference in lieu of the imminent conflict but does not let you know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org) for 3rd party dependencies.  Each project specifies which dependencies it has, and which versions of those dependencies it uses.  Upon build NuGet gets the required versions for you.

Download NuGet (if your version of VisualStudio doesn't already have it), install it, open the `Package Manager Console` window, and run something like `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`.  All done :)

---

As an alternative you can use [granadaCoders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496426/60724) approach, which was typical before dedicated dependency management tools (like NuGet, or maven).

A common approach there is to setup a Solution's directory structure like:

```
 .\bin   <-- if you're doing continuous integration then your most recently built
             versions are placed in the bin folder
 .\docs  <-- docs is a home for any documentation related to the project
 .\lib   <-- lib is the root of all your third-party dependencies
 .\lib\{packagename}\ <-- each package gets it's own folder, such as 
                          Newtonsoft.Json.  All projects reference the package 
                          from here with a relative path.  If you update the 
                          third party assembly then all dependent projects get 
                          the update.
 .\src   <-- src is the root of all your releasable source code
 .\src\MySolution.sln <-- your Solution
 .\src\AProject\ <-- each project gets its own folder in src for all its contents
 .\test   <-- test is the root for all your test projects (unit/integration/etc)
 .\test\AProjectTests\  <-- each test project gets its own folder
```

Comment: You can also use the package manager GUI if you're into that sort of thing. In VS2012: Click `Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`.

Answer (score 0):

I stay away from this world by:

Changing the folder structure to this:

```
.\MySolution.sln
.\MyFirstProject\MyFirstProject.csproj
.\MySecondProject\MySecondProject.csproj
.\MyThirdProject\MyThirdProject.csproj
.\MyOtherProject\SomeFolder\MyOtherProject.csproj
.\ThirdPartyReferences\
```

Put all of your referenced assemblies in ".\ThirdPartyReferences\".
Have all the csproj reference the .dll's using the "..\ThirdPartyReferences\MyCoolDll.dll"
(however many ".." you need)

The every csproj has to use the same version and originating location of any third party references.

Comment: Granada, this is exactly what I do, not exactly your file structure, but my intent is the same.  Although, not sure what your intent of MyCoolDLL.dll is, or just a dummy dll name?

Answer (score 0):

IF your project is a `WEB SITE` project, as opposed to a `WEB APPLICATION` project which is an entirely different thing... then this behavior is expected.

Essentially, when working with `Web Site` projects Visual Studio will redo your assembly references if it locates a version that is `GAC`'d or along any of the search paths.   This is absolutely maddening behavior and I have no idea why they thought it was a good thing.  But I digress.

In order to stop Visual Studio from doing this you have two choices.  Either convert the solution to a web application project (which you should be using anyway) then fix the references OR pull the assemblies it is referencing out of the `GAC`.

Truth be told, I recommend going ahead and doing both solutions.  `GAC`'ing assemblies is simply a bad idea and generally leads to a fair amount of unwanted behavior.  Of course, I know that some companies (Infragistics being one) that recommends installing their crap in the GAC.  The problem comes when you have multiple applications that have dependencies on different versions (especially web sites) and one gets updated...

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar problem at one point and solved it this way (I think it was in VS2010).

- Deleted the reference
- Added the new version dll
- Set "Copy Local" to false
- Clean Solution
- Build
- Set "Copy Local" back to true for dlls that require it

It seems kind of deceptively simple, but the process hasn't failed me since.